# AppleScript sending emails with attachment between contents

Tags: email, applescript, attachment

I'd like to send and email with apple script to do like this :

```
hi,
here is the attachment file
[The attachment.pdf]

As you can see, it is a good attachment
Thanks
Bye
```

I know how to use applescript to send an email with attachment at the end of the message, but not between 2 sentences.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work :

```
set _attachment to "Macintosh HD:Users:usr:Desktop:Form.pdf"

set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Here it is", content: "hi,
here is the attachment file"}

tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:_attachment as alias}

tell msg to add "As you can see, it is a good attachment
Thanks
Bye" as content
```

Thanks you all for your support.

Dam

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about `Apple Mail`, you can specify the location of the attachment in the content of the message.

The text of body is passed instantly and the attachment is inserted afterwards.

```
set _attachment to (path to desktop as text) & "Form.pdf"

tell application "Mail"
    set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Here it is", content:"hi,
here is the attachment file



As you can see, it is a good attachment
Thanks
Bye"}

    tell content of msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:_attachment as alias} at after third paragraph
end tell
```